# No connection is available to service this operation - Redis with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to access Redis(hosted on docker container) in a window service written in C#.net, I am using StackExchange.Redis SDK to access Redis, Whenever I try to access Redis, I am getting following error

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is
>   available to service this operation: FLUSHDB; UnableToConnect (None,
>   last-recv: 23) on 10.0.5.122:57457/Interactive, Flushed/ReadAsync,
>   last: ECHO, origin: ResetNonConnected, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s
>   ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state:
>   ConnectedEstablishing, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never,
>   global: 5s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402; IOCP:
>   (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=0,Free=32767,Min=2,Max=32767), Local-CPU: n/a --->
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: UnableToConnect (None,
>   last-recv: 23) on 10.0.5.122:57457/Interactive, Flushed/ReadAsync,
>   last: ECHO, origin: ResetNonConnected, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s
>   ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state:
>   ConnectedEstablishing, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never,
>   global: 5s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402\r\n --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---\r\n

I am using latest version of StackExchange.Redis, I also tried by downgrading version as suggested in couple of articles but no luck, I am also setting **AbortOnConnectFail** as false. Redis server is up and working fine, I can do telnet and also can see all keys through a tool(Redis React)

Strange things is that, same code is working fine when using in a website with same Redis server.

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Does the code work, if the programm is on the same computer as the server? If it does, this is a networking problem.

Comment: @Christopher Code work, Redis is hosted on different server, Code is working in web application but not in window service, both web application and window service are hosted on same server.

Comment: Then it is most likely a firewall issue. Propably the service was not given a Firewall exception.

Comment: @Christopher Firewall on docker machine where Redis is running or where windows service is running? Can you guide what changes needs to be done on firewall?

Comment: This is a question of Network adminsitration, not programming. And I can not help debug this. Only a Administator of those servers can do it.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your insight, Thank you

Comment: Your windows service should run with "Network Service" user in order to make network connections. You should check that.

Comment: @Eldar this didn't worked, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For some reason System.Numerics.Vectors.dll was not present in output folder, I copied this manually and it started working